Как добавить вторую клавишу, активирующую функцию в Turtle на Python?
Я хочу, чтобы функция buy происходила при нажатии не только "w", но еще и "ц", подскажите, как это сделать, код обрезан
import turtle

win.listen()
win.onkey(click, "space")
win.onkey(buy, "w")
while True:
    win.update()


Стоит убрать лишний код из вопроса и оставить только то что относится к обработке кнопки.
